# Javascript documentation on getParameterByName?

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to find any detailed documentation on getParameterByName(). I've searched Mozilla, Google, and here. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's a function and I read it wrong. I was trying to see how to collect information from a query string.

Comment: This is what you may be looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no builtin function with this name.

Have a look at [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) though - maybe that's the function you are looking for. It returns the querystring parameter with a given name.

Answer (score 16):

We use this where I work. Similar to ThiefMaster's solution...

```
function getParameterByName( name ){
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add validation of name is not null/undefined

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    if (name !== "" && name !== null && name != undefined) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    } else {
        var arr = location.href.split("/");
        return arr[arr.length - 1];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

because it does not exists. I think you want to look at : getElementsByTagName ? if not provide more information of what kind of method you search